# error while importing .swf file

Tags: java, xslt, flash

actually in our XSLT application we have added below code for adding .swf file.

```
<xsl:with-param name="src">/a/b/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:with-param>
```

This code is written by some previous developers. And I am not aware of xslt and flash file. Now I want to change location of Spreadsheet.swf file. And code will look like this -

```
<xsl:with-param name="src">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="$operating_environment='UAT' or $operating_environment='Test' or $operating_environment='Local'">https://www.***.com/docs/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>https://www.***.com/docs/xyz/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose></xsl:with-param>
```

When I am using above code to import .swf file it giving one error 
"**An error has occurred. Please contact your representative for further assistance.**" on browser.

Also I tried to open the file using flash player, but it is giving the same error.

We have used "swfobject.js" to prepare object from this .swf file.
From this object I am trying to read xml, but it is giving me blank value.

Since, this file is not getting imported properly, I am unable to get XML data from that object.

Please help me as soon as possible. I am very new to flash and xsl. And I have no idea about this error.

Maybe I can get solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016507/how-to-give-full-path-of-swf-file-using-xslwith-param). Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016507/how-to-give-full-path-of-swf-file-using-xslwith-param) question also

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the .swf is now on another server?

Comment: yes. you are right. it is on another server. But What should I do now?

Comment: I'm not a flash expert, but I know that there are security rules that prevent running flash files that have another origin than the html that refers to them.

Comment: Plus, it's possible that the .swf contains absolute references

Comment: it is not possible for me to open that file and check its content.

Comment: Is the first code sample written by the other developers? If yes, does it work if you keep same format like `<xsl:with-param name="src"> https://www.yorsite.com/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:with-param>`? Talk to (email) the previous developers about it? Show a link to the swf so we can check? (it may not run if swf's own code checks the address bar and sees it's not the original hard-coded one, a sort-of theft protection).

Comment: @VC.One : yes. That sample code is written by previous developer. And no one is available now. That code is written 10-15 years ago. And I am new to this organisation. I am not sure whether it will work or not as suggested by you. I will check it and then let you know.

Comment: @VC.One . I tried it. If we give previous swf file path using link it will not work. Now what should I do. It will work using <xsl:with-param name="src">/a/b/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:with-param>, 
but not work with <xsl:with-param name="src">https://mylink/a/b/Spreadsheet.swf</xsl:with-param>

Comment: previous file is also not working if we use it using link. So I think there is problem with link. Can't we use link in xsl param element

Comment: Do you have a page link to see this swf in action? The `/a/b/` in your link points to same thing as `mysite.com/a/b/` anyways so it's strange that it fails (like where does it think those sub-folders `/a/b/` are existing at?). I was hoping a **full** path would help. Provide a page link to check with my various tools what the real issue is...

Comment: if i use that full link on browser to check whether that file is present on that location or not, it is giving me same error as "An error has occurred. Please contact your representative for further assistance". 

We can open any image, css or js file using link. So why we can not open that file on browser using link.

Comment: Regarding when loading the swf file directly in browser (via full path)... Is the error actually inside the swf itself (to check : Right-click nearest to error text as possible, does it show some "Flash Player" version & options?) If Yes, the swf loaded correctly but its code failed to do something (so maybe previous developers coded it to show that message)... If not "Flash Player" text when you right-click then your error is likely from server provider or such (think 404 errors when you try going to some deleted or unavailable link).

Comment: Its also possible the swf does load correctly but its code tries to access a deleted file from old server. As a test just put swf on **its own html page** (no extras). Now in your browser open the Developer Tools (I use Chrome or Firefox for this), go to the "network" tab... Now when you go to html address the network tab should show **only** one item called _Spreadsheet.swf_. Now is there anymore new files listed after the swf? If yes then check if they exist by right-click and choose "open in new tab".

Comment: If still unsure, just provide a temporary link to the page (you can delete the comment later after its been checked)... Too much guessing about an "invisible" problem we can't see.

Comment: I could see the flash player version. That means it is loaded correctly,

Comment: in network tab all required files are present. Actually I can't give you actual link since I am not supposed to do it for the sake of dirty rules.But I really appreciate your initiative. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually we can not use link in xsl file. That might be the reason of failing. So i want to find out another way to give path of that swf file. If you no please suggest me some different ways